# Is there a way to highlight embedded JavaScript inside a XML CDATA Tag in VSCODE?

Tags: javascript, xml, visual-studio-code, cdata

I have a hard time analyzing JS code inside XML's CDATA tags since VSCODE highlights it in a single color like a comment. So is there a way to highlight the JavaScript code inside the XML CDATA tag?

The CDATA Tag for example.

```xml
<Script>
    <![CDATA[

      let x = myFunction(4, 3);   

      function myFunction(a, b) {
          return a * b;            
      }
            
    ]]>
</Script>
```

Comment: Try searching and installing various XML extension, probably someone have figured this one out.